# Connecting to SQL server through the internet using matlab JDBC

Tags: sql, matlab

I made a GUI software in Matlab that will access my SQL server database. So far, I have been able to access the database from all of the computers in my lab. However, these computers are all on the same network, and the database will need to be accessed through networks outside of the lab. I can already access my database using another instance of SQL Server from my home. My question is, is it possible to access my database from an outside network using Matlab and the JDBC driver?

Comment: Yes, if you have control of the necessary firewalls.

Comment: Have you seen it done before?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the TechNet article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Main things are: TCP/IP libraries enabled on SQL Server(that better be on anyway). Incoming ports enabled. Defaults are TCP 1433 and UDP 1434, but you may have changed those during installation if you used named instances of SQL SErver.